# Are the new Marvel Star Wars comics Legends canon?

Tags: star-wars, marvel

Has there been any word on what level of canon the new Star Wars comics being produced by Marvel are?

Specifically, are they in continuity with the new movies and the Rebels TV show or are they considered part of the Legends canon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All officially licensed material (aside from obvious parody things like the LEGO Star Wars shorts) are fully (New Disney) canon. They are not Legends canon.

Back in the [canon purge](http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page), the specifically mentioned new comics were to be published.

> “We have an unprecedented slate of new Star Wars entertainment on the horizon,” said Kennedy. **“We’re set to bring Star Wars back to the big screen, and continue the adventure through games, books, comics, and new formats that are just emerging.** This future of interconnected storytelling will allow fans to explore this galaxy in deeper ways than ever before.”

Everything in the comics has been overseen and approved.

> Now, with an exciting future filled with new cinematic installments of Star Wars, all aspects of Star Wars storytelling moving forward will be connected. Under Lucasfilm President Kathleen Kennedy’s direction, the company for the first time ever has formed a story group to oversee and coordinate all Star Wars creative development.

Currently, Marvel is the only company with rights to publish Star Wars comics (which makes sense, as they are also a Disney subsidiary).